# Trying to use libcurl in my program and getting "undefined reference" errors

Tags: c, linker-errors, libcurl, undefined-reference

I am getting the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccno287V.o: In function `download_feed':

feedObtain.c:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
feedObtain.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
feedObtain.c:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
feedObtain.c:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Command used to get libcurl:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-gnut
```

Comment: Show your compiler/linker commands.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not linked with the libcurl library and hence the linker complains that it could resolve symbols. Link the library with:

```
cc feedObtain.c -lcurl
```

Note that the library must be specified at the end of the commandline options.